# Android get notifications when HttpPost (JSON , Mysql,PHP) change on the mysql

Tags: android

I am writing an Android app for our system (for example ping state..storage,,exp) that needs to be notified whenever a change in the database it notify the app..
I just need to know how i can get notifications when HttpPost change it data...

thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with Push Notifications try GCM from google